# What's more important in SEO: Title or link data?

Tags: seo

I'm developing a store locator web site where users may search for a brand and get a list of stores selling this brand.

Now I'm doing some SEO. My goal is that when someone is googling for a store name or storename + city, then my site will be listed on page one.

If you visit a store on my site today, the title will show:
`storename, city, country - at mysite.com`

My URL will look like this:
`http://mysite.com/store/?store=Mardou+&+Dean&storeid=5459`

My question is:
- Should I add city name and country in my URL?
- Would it be good or bad in terms of SEO to have this url:
`http://mysite.com/store/Norway/Oslo/Mardou+&+Dean/?storeid=5459`

In terms of usability,the last url is best, but not sure if it matters to search engines?

I know that there is a lot more to SEO, but now I'm just wondering about this part.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much information you want to expose to search engine, you should adjust the data used in these `Microdata`.

This article is worth reading:

http://www.vanseodesign.com/web-design/html5-microdata/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `Microdata`. Do you know what effect these extra attributes have on different browsers?

Comment: Microdata is defined in HTML5. Thus, browsers support HTML5 supports Microdata; else, the tags are simply ignored. Anyway, the tags are for search engines, not for normal users.

Answer (score 0):

The impact of keywords in the URL is not as important as you think. Ensuring that your targeted terms are in the page title, content and headings, internal and external backlink anchor text etc are all much more powerful signals.

Don't confuse "exact match domains" with exact match URLs.

For more "educated" "opinion" on what matters, take a look at http://www.seomoz.org/article/search-ranking-factors